# BIM 360 Field API Issues V1: GET Request works perfectly with Postman, responds "Unauthorized" with RestSharp

Tags: api, field, postman, restsharp, autodesk-bim360

Trying to implement `var client = new RestClient("https://bim360field.autodesk.com/fieldapi/checklists/v1/06eede44-a707-4f0b-9529-78abea6e6bf5");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);` https://bim360field.autodesk.com/apidoc/index.html#fieldapi/checklists/v1/checklists_api_method_2 in my C# solution.

I've set up an example Get Request in Postman. Works perfectly with the form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded, no auth, bearer token.
Tried to copy the exact Restshap Request code from Postman to my C# app. Does not work; always responds with "Unauthorized". Tried changing cookie mngmt, and auth window/nltm mngmt. Did not help.

````
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
request.AddHeader("Content-Length", "91");
request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "OPTOUTMULTI_REF=b7027893-8564-4b33-8f1e-de0c175d38c6; OPTOUTMULTI_GEO=NL; utag_main=v_id:016639c85215001e1ab9f566c61201090006808800bd0$_sn:4$_ss:0$_st:1545042741235$ses_id:1545040922510%3Bexp-session$_pn:1%3Bexp-session; XSRF-TOKEN=YxM2BdzM19rML7OjKGZqcD0hAqv%2F225McEm8oB3m7No%3D; 75da74d446a8376e2cf6a286ff63573ab705f04c36540fdda21c1dbc1928d4e72cabf30a63e339690e88fc3801a93e44e6e3ddc20651f602d2c5eaaf49b21d61=f795a05c211085d994bf2e08996ff747");
request.AddHeader("Host", "bim360field.autodesk.com");
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "0b3c652d-462c-4aba-a661-476309792018,b4d4846c-a928-406f-837c-f16809a9bccd");
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.15.2");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"ticket\"\r\n\r\n{API_TICKET}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"project_id\"\r\n\r\n049bf984-b8d1-4330-a17c-0832c6facf49\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);```

I expect that this code is also working with Restsharp. Do I miss anything?
````

Answer (score 0):

1. For your cookies you will need to setup a CookieContainer on your Client.

   `Client = new RestClient(Request.GetEnvironment())
    {
        CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer()
    };`
2. You don't need the Postman Token. You will want to use the Bearer Token provided by your API to make the call and add it to your headers or parameters.
3. When intializing RestClient you only want to pass the base url. Then pass the rest of your api path during the RestRequest initialization. This will help for future use when wanting to hit more than one end point with the same cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example for you:

```
// (1) Build request 
var client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = new System.Uri("https://bim360field.autodesk.com/");

// Set resource or end point 
var request = new RestRequest();
request.Resource = "/fieldapi/checklists/v1";
request.Method = Method.GET;

// Add parameters 
request.AddParameter("ticket", "{API_TICKET}");
request.AddParameter("project_id", "049bf984-b8d1-4330-a17c-0832c6facf49");

// (2) Execute request and get response
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Hope it helps!